# WildFly performance

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I have been using WildFly in domain mode to serve some applications, each application has its own datasource and configured pool, however I'm having some issues that I don't know how to solve without any urgency.

When one of the applications is slow to finish some database operation or for taking a new connection from the pool, the whole container slows down and gives the feeling that everything just crashed. This is an annoying behavior that I would like to know if WildFly can avoid with some configuration, because normally I have to flush the pool with the issue to recover the whole system.

PS: I'm using WildFly 13

*Edit:
I have three domain server configured into WildFly, each one have several web applications. The problem described can happen in any of them and only that domain server gets blocked. Towards the database everything is fine, not blocking queries or process.*

Comment: Do they share the same database? Each domain server is a new process so one process shouldn't slow down another.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins actually that behavior is fine, they don't block each other, I have three domain server configured into WildFly, each one have several web applications. The problem described can happen in any of them and only that domain server gets blocked. Towards the database everything is fine, not blocking queries or process

Comment: Ah okay. The error could be important to the issue. It's tough to tell what it could be with the information given.

Comment: I try to monitor the issue with an APM, it has happen with different databases (tested with Oracle and PostgreSQL), the only I can see is the latency in the current transaction and how seems that WidlFly process in a serial way, as the APM shows them in an incremental way. Lets say we have 5 applications and each one has its own pool, why the response time of one single query can hold the others in a sort of stand by status if they belong to different pools?